# docker-compose yaml - mapping values are not allowed here

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml

What is wrong with my `docker-compose.yml` file ?
docker-compose complains:

```
docker-compose up                                                                                                             ERROR: yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here
  in ".\docker-compose.yml", line 7, column 16
```

---

This is my `socker-compose.yml`

```
version: '2.0'
services:
  cass1:
    image: cassandra
  cass2:
    image cassandra
    environment:
      - CASSANDRA_SEEDS=cass1
    depends_on:
      - "cass1"
  cass4:
    image cassandra
    environment:
      - CASSANDRA_SEEDS=cass1     
    depends_on:
      - "cass1"
```

I'am looking at the docker-compose's documentation here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/ and this example is similar to my file:

> **Set environment variables in containers**
>
> You can set environment variables in a service’s containers with the ‘environment’ key, just
> like with docker run -e VARIABLE=VALUE ...:
>
> ```
> web:
>   environment:
>     - DEBUG=1
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the colon on the previous line. Change `image cassandra` to `image: cassandra`.